# Live template with predefined list of variable and complex logic of add parameters

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

I want create live template for generate `fa-icons`. For example next

```
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right align-top bigger-125"></i>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left icon-on-left bigger-140"></i>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-times icon-on-right"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Rules to generate is next:

1. Minimum generated template is `<i class="fa fa-$ICON_NAME$"></i>`
2. Need to have ability add classes `ace-icon` and if it is added setup `icon-on-[right|left]`
3. If `$ICON_NAME$` is `fa-arrow-[right|left]` and setted `ace-icon` set direction part as it setted in `icon-on-[right|left]`
4. Has ability to optional write aditional classes like `align-top` in example
5. If setup `$SIZE$` in `bigger-$SIZE$` add this class else skip
6. Options of `$ICON_NAME$` and `$SIZE$` must be predefined.

Assumed live template

```
<i class="$ACE_CLASS$ fa fa-$ICON_NAME$ icon-on-$ACE_DIRECTION$ $OPTIONAL_CLASS$ bigger-$SIZE$"></i>
```

My questions:

1. How to setup predefined option list for `$ICON_NAME$`, `$ACE_DIRECTION$`  and `$SIZE$`?
2. How to not render `bigger-$SIZE$` if size is empty?
3. How check if `$ICON_NAME$` contains `$ACE_DIRECTION$` and switch it?
4. How to render `icon-on-$ACE_DIRECTION$` and  `bigger-$SIZE$` only if `$ACE_CLASS$` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to setup predefined option list for `$ICON_NAME$`, `$ACE_DIRECTION$` and `$SIZE$`?

`enum(sCompletionString1,sCompletionString2,...)` -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/live-template-variables.html#predefined_functions

---

> How to not render `bigger-$SIZE$` if size is empty?

Not possible -- Live Templates do not have [conditions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6446) or [loops](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7252).

I may only suggest to have another `enum` with all `bigger-XXX` options, including empty one (basically -- instead of `bigger-$SIZE$` have `$BIGGER-SIZE$`).

2017.2 should have **[GroovyScript support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36141)** -- maybe you can then [code your own Live Template function](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155907#comment=27-1439417) or something ([see this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155907#comment=27-1439617) for some doc links)...

---

> How check if `$ICON_NAME$` contains `$ACE_DIRECTION$` and switch it?

Same as above: not possible -- Live Templates do not have conditions.

---

> How to render `icon-on-$ACE_DIRECTION$` and `bigger-$SIZE$` only if `$ACE_CLASS$` is true?

Same as above: not possible -- Live Templates do not have conditions.

You may create more than one Live Template that would cover few different scenarios (they would have different abbreviations, of course: e.g. `fai` for one case, `fai2` for another etc).

Comment: Can I call one live template from other? For example `<button>fai</button>`

Comment: I guess you mean this -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6414. Not possible. You need to end first live template first .. as `[Tab]` key (the most often used expand key for Live Templates) is also the key used for navigating from one variable/placeholder to another in current template. Try assigning another custom expand key (not `Space`, `Tab` or `Enter`) -- maybe it will work that way.

Comment: @PavloZhukov Or the question was -- "reference live template inside another live template and expand them both at the same time"? The answer is the same -- not possible (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24014 marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6414).

Comment: Please see if there is [that feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674790/get-new-file-when-compare-branches) in PhpStorm?

Comment: @PavloZhukov Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave feature request for a while